# What is the effect of adding &gt; prefix to an XML attribute's value?

Tags: xml

I understand that `&gt;` is the HTML symbol for `>`.

Checking the code of an app at GitHub, I realized an object definition was sometimes prefixed with 2 `>` characters.

What is the effect of doing this?

### Example (from ShareX)

Here, the name is directly `btnAdd`

```
<data name="btnAdd.TabIndex" type="System.Int32, mscorlib">
    <value>0</value>
  </data>
  <data name="btnAdd.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Add...</value>
  </data>
```

Here, it is `>>btnAdd`

```
  <data name="&gt;&gt;btnAdd.Name" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>btnAdd</value>
  </data>
  <data name="&gt;&gt;btnAdd.Type" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>System.Windows.Forms.Button, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, </value>
</data>
```

Comment: _"What is the effect of doing this?"_ - That depends entirely on the application code that processes this XML document. As far as the XML specification is concerned this XML is valid (unless there's a speciifc restriction on the use of entity references in this attribute in this XML document's XML Schema or SGML DTD).

Answer (score 1):

```
name="&gt;&gt;btnAdd.Name"
```

This is specifying the value of the 'name' attribute of the `<data>` element as the string `>>btnAdd.Name`.  The value is just plain text, of no particular significance within XML.  Its value may be significant to whatever process *uses* the XML, but as far as XML itself is concerned, it's just a string value like any other.